# Creating t-sql procedure and output the contents

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

*I am trying to create a stored procedure and I am so lost. I have included what I have done so far, but I know for sure I am missing a few things and can't figure it out. please help!*

Question I am trying to solve:

Obtain the name and credit limit of the customer whose number currently stored in I_customer_num. place these values in the variables I_customer_name and I_credit_limit. Output the content of I_customer_name and I_credit_limit.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_DISP_NAME_CREDIT 
@CUSTOMERNUM char(3) 
AS 

SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, CREDIT_LIMIT 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE CUSTOMER_NUM = @CUSTOMERNUM
```

Comment: What happens s when you execute that entire statement that you pasted?  Do you get an error?  What is it?

Answer (score 1):

this is the way its done in sql server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <Procedure_Name, sysname, ProcedureName> 
    <@Param1, sysname, @p1>
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT .......................
END
GO
```

also if you are using sql-server go to your database then programmability then in stored procedures right click then click on new stored procedure